# Which script initialized module?

Tags: perl, logging, perl-module, log4perl

In Perl, is there any way to tell which .pl script has initialized **this** instance of a module?

Specifically, I'd like to get the name of the script calling a module, which has a `Log4perl` object it. That way, I'll know which .log file I want to write to within the module.

Am I doing this wrong? If I define the `$logger` in my .pl script, will any `$logger` calls within the module write to the same .log file as the calling script?

I don't have any sample code yet, but have been reading up on `Log4perl`. Basically, if I set an Appender to a file, `caller.log`, which is the file appender for my calling script, `caller.pl`, I'd want any logging defined in the custom imported module, to also write to `caller.log` (implicitly, if possible -- obviously I could just pass the name of the log name when I initialize the module instance).

Is this possible without passing arguments specifying which File Appender the module should write to? Doesn't `Log4perl` use just one `$logger` instance?

Also, let me know if I'm way out, and if there's a different approach I should be considering.

Thank you

**EDIT:** Sorry, after I posted this, I looked at the Related Links, and I guess my search wording just wasn't correct. It looks like this is a pretty good solution: [Self logging Perl modules (without Moose)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267486/self-logging-perl-modules-without-moose)

If anyone has any other ideas, though, please let me know.

**EDIT 2:** Finally tested, and got it to work as I had wanted -- was a lot easier than  was making it out to be, too!

This is my setup, pretty much:

### Module.pm

```
package Module;

use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger :levels);
use Data::Dumper;

my $logger = get_logger("Module");

sub new {
    my ($class, $name) = @_;

    my @caller = caller(0);
    $logger->debug("Creating new Module. Called by " . Dumper(\@caller));

    my $object = { 'name' => $name };

    return bless($object, $class);  
}
```

### caller.pl

```
use Module;
use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger :levels);
use Data::Dumper;

my $PATH = "$ENV{'APPS'}/$ENV{'OUTDIR'}";
my $SCRIPT = "caller";

my $logger = get_logger("Module");
$logger->level($DEBUG);

my $file_appender = Log::Log4perl::Appender->new("Log::Dispatch::File", 
                        filename=> "$PATH/$SCRIPT.log", 
                        mode => "append",);
$logger->add_appender($file_appender);

my $layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout->new("%d %p> %F{1}:%L %M - %m%n");
$file_appender->layout($layout);

my $lib = Module->new('Chris');

$logger->info(Dumper($lib));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass Log4perl, overriding its constructor. In your custom constructor, use `caller()` to get the filename that called the constructor and put it in `$self`.

Comment: Thanks. Not a bad idea. I may have another module is which a base for the module I've discussed -- and that could at least have a pseudo-constructor for creating the $logger instance.

Comment: How would you then suggest calling $logger, without extracting it from the instance variable? Make it a global variable (not ideal), or would I just have to do (in caller.pl) my $logger = get_logger("SubModule") and SubModule would have my $logger = get_logger("Module") ?

Comment: You can use SUPER for calling the superclass version: `$class->SUPER::get_logger( @_ );`

Comment: OK, so if in my calling script, if I do `my $logger = get_logger("Module")` and I specify a $logger of "Module" in Module.pm, then add a File Appender in caller.pl, all $logger calls will write to the one .log file?

Comment: If your goal is to have everything go to the same log file, then perhaps a better approach is to setup a Log::Log4perl config where `log4perl.rootLogger=LOGFILE`, and then build an appender `LOGFILE`.  As long as the config doesn't have any other loggers defined, everything will go there.

Comment: Well, the log file name is all script-caller specific. So another process, caller2.pl, may require the same Module caller.pl did, but has "caller2.log" to write to. In that case, I'll want any $logger calls within Module to write to "caller2.log"

Answer (score 2):

You can put a subroutine hook into `@INC` that can run arbitrary code, as documented in [`perldoc -f require`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#require). For example:

```
# UseLogger.pm
package UseLogger;
sub import { unshift @INC, \&UseLogger::log_use }
sub log_use {
    my ($self, $filename) = @_;
    my @c = caller(0);
    print "Module $filename required in file $c[1] line $c[2]\n";
    return 0;
}
1;

$ perl -MUseLogger my_script.pl
Module feature.pm required in file my_script.pl line 2
Module Encode.pm required in file my_script.pl line 5
Module XSLoader.pm from /usr/lib/perl5/5.14.0/cygwin-thread-multi-64int/Encode.pm line 13
...
```

Comment: Interesting. I think I can get away with the default Log4perl use -- using the logger defined in the Module class, and adding FileAppenders in the calling scripts as needed.

Answer (score 2):

`$0` contains the path to the script. You can use File::Basename's `basename` if you want to want the file name component.

Comment: Duh! I knew that! :p but figured that was for the actual file $0 was in -- didn't know it was related to the calling script (but tested, and sure enough..)

Comment: @Chris Serra, `__FILE__` is the file that contains `__FILE__`.

Comment: @Chris Serra, There's no such thing as a "calling script". A module is *loaded*, and it's not necessarily loaded by a *script*. I'm assuming you want the path to the script Perl is executing.

Comment: Good point, ikegami. Only time there'd be a true calling script, is if you ised system() or exec() within one script to run another. But in this case, I am loading a module.